# MySQL optimizing view

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm working on an *ASP.NET* application that use the following query to retrieve data to feed into a *GridView*.
The query works seems to work fine but it's very very slow to complete (even if run trough MySQL Workbench).
With a pretty poor database (i.e. not with as much data as it supposed to be populated) the query take around 7 seconds to complete.
The query is defined as a View in **MySQL** and it's bound to the *GridView* trough an *SQLDataSource*.
I would like to optimize it but I'm not that good in SQL.

```
SELECT 
        `noleggio`.`iddocumento` AS `iddocumento`,
        `noleggio`.`numero` AS `numero`,
        `noleggio`.`serie` AS `serie`,
        `noleggio`.`data` AS `data`,
        `noleggio`.`anno` AS `anno`,
        `noleggio`.`cliente_ragione_sociale` AS `cliente_ragione_sociale`,
        `noleggio`.`imponibile` AS `imponibile`,
        `noleggio`.`totale` AS `totale`,
        `noleggio`.`tipo_documento` AS `tipo_documento`,
        `noleggio`.`tipo_documento_dettaglio` AS `tipo_documento_dettaglio`,
        `noleggio`.`data_pagamento` AS `data_pagamento`,
        `noleggio`.`aliquota_ritenuta_acconto` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_acconto`,
        `noleggio`.`ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile`,
        `noleggio`.`aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco`,
        `noleggio`.`re_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `re_percentuale_importo_imponibile`,
        `noleggio`.`id_noleggio` AS `id_noleggio`,
        `stati`.`data_stato` AS `data_stato`,
        `stati`.`stato` AS `stato_sdi`,
        `noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione`.`data_incasso_saldo` AS `data_incasso_saldo`
    FROM
        (((SELECT 
            `noleggio`.`iddocumento` AS `iddocumento`,
                `noleggio`.`numero` AS `numero`,
                `noleggio`.`serie` AS `serie`,
                `noleggio`.`data` AS `data`,
                `noleggio`.`anno` AS `anno`,
                `noleggio`.`cliente_ragione_sociale` AS `cliente_ragione_sociale`,
                `noleggio`.`imponibile` AS `imponibile`,
                `noleggio`.`totale` AS `totale`,
                `noleggio`.`tipo_documento` AS `tipo_documento`,
                `noleggio`.`tipo_documento_dettaglio` AS `tipo_documento_dettaglio`,
                `noleggio`.`data_pagamento` AS `data_pagamento`,
                `noleggio`.`aliquota_ritenuta_acconto` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_acconto`,
                `noleggio`.`ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile`,
                `noleggio`.`aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco`,
                `noleggio`.`re_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `re_percentuale_importo_imponibile`,
                `doc_righe`.`id_noleggio` AS `id_noleggio`
        FROM
            (`doc_righe`
        JOIN (SELECT 
            `doc_testa`.`id` AS `iddocumento`,
                `doc_testa`.`numero` AS `numero`,
                `doc_testa`.`serie` AS `serie`,
                `doc_testa`.`data` AS `data`,
                `doc_testa`.`anno` AS `anno`,
                `doc_testa`.`cliente_ragione_sociale` AS `cliente_ragione_sociale`,
                `doc_testa`.`imponibile` AS `imponibile`,
                `doc_testa`.`totale` AS `totale`,
                `doc_testa`.`tipo_documento` AS `tipo_documento`,
                `doc_testa`.`tipo_documento_dettaglio` AS `tipo_documento_dettaglio`,
                `doc_testa`.`data_pagamento` AS `data_pagamento`,
                `doc_testa`.`aliquota_ritenuta_acconto` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_acconto`,
                `doc_testa`.`ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile`,
                `doc_testa`.`aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco` AS `aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco`,
                `doc_testa`.`re_percentuale_importo_imponibile` AS `re_percentuale_importo_imponibile`
        FROM
            `doc_testa`) `noleggio` ON ((`noleggio`.`iddocumento` = `doc_righe`.`id_testa`)))
        GROUP BY `noleggio`.`iddocumento`) `noleggio`
        LEFT JOIN `noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione` ON ((`noleggio`.`id_noleggio` = `noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione`.`id_noleggio`)))
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
            `transizioni_sdi`.`id` AS `id`,
                `transizioni_sdi`.`id_doc` AS `id_doc`,
                MAX(`transizioni_sdi`.`data_stato`) AS `data_stato`,
                `tab_stati_sdi`.`stato` AS `stato`
        FROM
            (`transizioni_sdi`
        JOIN `tab_stati_sdi` ON ((`tab_stati_sdi`.`id` = `transizioni_sdi`.`stato`)))
        GROUP BY `transizioni_sdi`.`id_doc`) `stati` ON ((`noleggio`.`iddocumento` = `stati`.`id_doc`)))
    ORDER BY `noleggio`.`numero`;
```

Please note that in original that query was using **RIGHT JOIN** statements but when I saved it as a View into MySQl WB  the editor for some reason *solved* **RIGHT JOINS** with this structure.
This was the original query:

```
SELECT 
    noleggio.*,
    stati.data_stato AS data_stato,
    stati.stato AS stato_sdi,
    data_incasso_saldo
FROM
    noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione
        RIGHT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        noleggio.*, id_noleggio
    FROM
        doc_righe
    JOIN (SELECT 
        id AS iddocumento,
            anno,
            numero,
            serie,
            data,
            cliente_ragione_sociale,
            imponibile,
            totale,
            tipo_documento,
            tipo_documento_dettaglio,
            data_pagamento,
            aliquota_ritenuta_acconto,
            ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile,
            aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco,
            re_percentuale_importo_imponibile
    FROM
        doc_testa) AS noleggio ON noleggio.iddocumento = doc_righe.id_testa
    GROUP BY iddocumento) AS noleggio ON noleggio.id_noleggio = noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione.id_noleggio
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        transizioni_sdi.id,
            id_doc,
            MAX(data_stato) AS data_stato,
            tab_stati_sdi.stato AS stato
    FROM
        transizioni_sdi
    INNER JOIN tab_stati_sdi ON tab_stati_sdi.id = transizioni_sdi.stato
    GROUP BY id_doc) AS stati ON noleggio.iddocumento = stati.id_doc
ORDER BY numero DESC;
```

The query was meant to find all **doc_testa** records with at least one matching record in **doc_righe** (always true in this application) the only needed field from **doc_righe** is **id_noleggio** (of course such field value could be *null*). **id_noleggio** is used to find match in **noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione** (if any) and retrieve **data_incasso_saldo** value. For all **doc_testa** record we need then to find the last matching **tab_stati_sdi.stato** value (if any).

Comment: "The query works fine but it's very very slow to complete" i doubt about the just fine part because it looks like you are using GROUP BY completely wrong..Using non aggregated columns in the SELECT clause which are not in the GROUP BY clause is just plain wrong which can generate **invalid results** in MySQL

Comment: @RaymondNijland at the present moment I had no issues but maybe depends on luck. Can you suggest a fix? What I need to do here is to find the last status entry in **transizioni_sdi** (if any) for each of the element in **doc_testa** table.

Comment: "at the present moment I had no issues but maybe depends on luck." luck no much more like playing russian roulette "Can you suggest a fix?" No but nobody can not without knowing table structures or example data and expected results..  i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please include the execution plan.

Comment: @RaymondNijland which of the two **GROUP BY** statement you're referring to?

Comment: @weirdgyn two easy rule how to use GROUP BY: 1) use GROUP BY only when you have aggregated columns and non-aggregated columns in SELECT. 2) List all non aggregated columns in GROUP BY. This will take care most use cases and will never go wrong. In your example both GROUP BY's are wrong: 1st subquery's GROUP BY violates 1) and the 2nd subquery's GROUP BY violates 2).

Comment: @slaakso thnx. I'm trying to understand what clearly this query was doing (I didn't write it and the coder that created it it's not available). It will take some time I will probably rewrite it from scratch (following rules of course).

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm working on it but it will take some time.. I'm not very used at it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    doc_testa.id AS iddocumento,
    doc_testa.numero AS numero,
    doc_testa.serie AS serie,
    doc_testa.data AS data,
    doc_testa.anno AS anno,
    doc_testa.tipo_documento_dettaglio AS tipo_documento_dettaglio,
    doc_testa.tipo_documento AS tipo_documento,
    doc_testa.cliente_ragione_sociale AS cliente_ragione_sociale,
    doc_testa.totale AS totale,
    doc_testa.imponibile AS imponibile,
    doc_testa.re_percentuale_importo_imponibile AS re_percentuale_importo_imponibile,
    doc_testa.aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco AS aliquota_ritenuta_enasarco,
    doc_testa.ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile AS ra_percentuale_importo_imponibile,
    doc_testa.aliquota_ritenuta_acconto AS aliquota_ritenuta_acconto,
    doc_testa.data_pagamento AS data_pagamento,
    noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione.data_incasso_saldo AS data_incasso_saldo,
    (SELECT 
            tab_stati_sdi.stato
        FROM
            transizioni_sdi
                INNER JOIN
            tab_stati_sdi ON tab_stati_sdi.id = transizioni_sdi.stato
        WHERE
            transizioni_sdi.id_doc = doc_testa.id
        ORDER BY transizioni_sdi.id DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS stato_sdi,
    noleggio_veicoli.numero AS numero_noleggio,
    noleggio_veicoli.serie AS serie_noleggio
FROM
    doc_righe
        LEFT JOIN
    doc_testa ON doc_righe.id_testa = doc_testa.id
        LEFT JOIN
    noleggio_veicoli ON noleggio_veicoli.id = doc_righe.id_noleggio
        LEFT JOIN
    noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione ON noleggio_veicoli.id = noleggio_veicoli_fatturazione.id_noleggio
ORDER BY numero DESC;
```